# VLC: Move file on end

Tags: c#, .net, vlc, libvlc, vlcj

In Windows, after double-clicking a video file, when it's finished, I want the file to be moved up a dir or 2, and any containing folder deleted.

I only want this to affect files located in `C:\Users\User1\Downloads`, say `%x%`.

There are 2 scenarios:

1. If the file is `%x%\Training.4273865.2013.avi`, it should be moved to `..\Viewed\`.
2. If the file is `%x%\Showcase\SomeFile.mp4`, it should be moved to the same folder: `..\..\Viewed\`. The `Showcase` folder should then be deleted. Currently, I have to close VLC (to close the file handle) before `Showcase` (and it's other contents) can be deleted.

A [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) solution would be good, but I don't mind any language I can compile with [visual-studio-2012](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2012) or similar open-source compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example C# application that can do what you're asking. Launch it by right clicking a video file, choosing Open With, and selecting the C# application's executable (you can check the box for "Always use the selected program to open this kind of file" to make the change permanent).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length < 1)
        return;

    string vlc = @"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe";
    string videoFile = args[0];
    string pathAffected = @"C:\Users\User1\Downloads";
    string destinationPath = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(pathAffected).FullName;
    destinationPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(destinationPath, @"Viewed\");

    Process vlcProcess = new Process();
    vlcProcess.StartInfo.FileName = vlc;
    vlcProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + videoFile + "\"";
    vlcProcess.StartInfo.Arguments += " --play-and-exit";
    vlcProcess.Start();
    vlcProcess.WaitForExit();

    if (videoFile.IndexOf(pathAffected,
        StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
    {
        System.IO.File.Move(videoFile,
            System.IO.Path.Combine(destinationPath,
            System.IO.Path.GetFileName(videoFile)));

        if (IsSubfolder(pathAffected, 
            System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(videoFile)))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.Delete(
                System.IO.Directory.GetParent(videoFile).FullName, true);
        }
    }

}
```

I found the code for `IsSubfolder` in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525775/how-to-check-if-directory-1-is-a-subdirectory-of-dir2-and-vice-versa).

Comment: Thank for the great answer, I've awarded you the bounty! One question: is there a way to only move the file if VLC actually played the full video and voluntarily exited? As it stands, if I close VLC in the middle of a video, the file is moved anyway. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty! I am not aware of a signal from VLC that indicates it completed the entire video. You might try posting that as a separate question and see if someone out there knows the answer.

Comment: Hey, I've been using this program a lot recently, so thanks a lot for it! Just one thing, when the video is in a subdir with other files, the other files get deleted (good), but the dir itself isn't deleted. When I try to manually delete it in Windows straight after, I get a file handle problem. About 3-5 seconds later, I can delete the subdir. How can I make your solution work fully? Is there a way to wait for the handle on the dir to be released? Or close the handle first? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could write a wrapper and associate it with your media files.

Which would indirectly launch VLC and then move files about once it closes.

VLC takes a list of streams as arguments, append `vlc://quit` to the end of your playlist to automatic exit VLC.

A wrapper written in C# would be more flexible, but here's a quick example in batch.

```
set VLC=C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe
set FILE=Tig Notaro - Live.mp3
start "VLC" /WAIT "%VLC%" "%FILE%" vlc://quit
echo VLC has closed, I can move the file.
move "%FILE%" old/
pause
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer William! I know I said a [tag:c#] or [tag:batch] solution would be good, but the [tag:c#] solution is, as you said, more flexible. Thanks for the effort!