# Avoid multiple FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, filepath, file-watcher

I am currently working on a custom explorer that allows the user to define multiple root directories. To capture all changes in the system, I use a `FileSystemWatcher` for all specified root directories.

Now, of course, it can happen that the user defines two root directories that contain the same paths. For example, `C:\Windows` and `C:\Windows\System32\en-US`

Then, when a file in these paths is modified (e.g. `C:\Windows\System32\en-US\Licenses`), the corresponding event handler is executed twice.

**So is there a way to compare FileSystemWatchers using the observed paths and exclude all duplicates?**

I already thought about assigning a single `FileSystemWatcher` to all paths and accordingly not watching the subpaths. But I assume that this is not quite as performant.

FYI:

```
foreach (string rootPath in Settings.RootPaths)
{
    FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(rootPath);

    watcher.SynchronizingObject = this.treeView;
    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Attributes
                            | NotifyFilters.CreationTime
                            | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName
                            | NotifyFilters.FileName
                            | NotifyFilters.LastAccess
                            | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                            | NotifyFilters.Security
                            | NotifyFilters.Size;
    watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    watcher.Created += ElementCreatedEventHandler;
    watcher.Deleted += ElementDeletedEventHandler;
    watcher.Renamed += ElementRenamedEventHandler;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check if rootpath1 is a subdir of another rootpath2, in that case you only need FileSystemWatcher on rootpath2.

To check is subdir you can look at

[How to check if directory 1 is a subdirectory of dir2 and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525775/how-to-check-if-directory-1-is-a-subdirectory-of-dir2-and-vice-versa)

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you! I've also come up with it in the meantime and was just about to post my solution :P

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you mean `FileSystemWatcher`, there is this: [FileSystemWatcher.Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.filter?view=net-6.0#System_IO_FileSystemWatcher_Filter).  The class maintains a filter collection which you can get through the property `FileSystemWatcher.Filters`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Yes, I meant `FileSystemWatcher`. I think it would be very unhandy (if not impossible) to exclude all duplicate paths from two `FileSystemWatcher` by the `FileSystemWatcher.Filter` Property. Please note that there may be a lot of duplicates.